# Create a String buffer in Swift for C to consume and free later

Tags: c, swift, ffi

**Quick form of the question for those who know Rust:** is there a Swift 5 equivalent of `std::ffi::CString` that can own a String and turn it into a `char*` like [into_raw](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw) and later free/drop it using something like [from_raw](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw)?

**Longer version:**

I have a C API that I am consuming in Swift. I have to supply a callback function, which I am supplying as a closure argument, and that closure must return a null-terminated string as a `const char *`—in Swift this is typed as `UnsafePointer<Int8>?`.

Clearly somebody has to be responsible for that memory and when it will be freed. In this case I would like to say that it is heap-allocated, and Swift is responsible for it and it will keep that `const char *` alive until the C interface finishes with it and calls some sort of `free()` function.

What is the least painful way to allocate some memory in Swift initialised with a UTF-8 string, provide a `const char *` to C, then free it later when instructed?

Comment: Is the string generated dynamically by the callback or can it be pre-generated i.e. does the callback always return the same string?

Comment: It will be dynamically created. My intention is to stuff the object that owns the dynamically-allocated memory in an array or map to keep it alive until I receive the corresponding free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible options:

```
let swiftString = "Hello world"
swiftString.withCString { cStringPtr in
    // use `cStringPtr` ...

}
```

calls the closure with a pointer a C string representation of the Swift string (UTF-8 encoded). That pointer is only valid during the execution of the closure.

For a longer lifetime, you can do

```
let swiftString = "Hello world"
let cStringPtr = strdup(swiftString)
// use `cStringPtr` ...
```

which allocates a new C String from the given Swift string, and release that memory later with

```
free(cStringPtr)
```

Comment: Or deallocate with `cStringPtr?.deallocate()` to be a bit more Swifty.

Comment: @JeremyP: No. `.deallocate()` happens to be equivalent to `free()` (on Apple platforms) but that is not guaranteed. See the discussion at https://forums.swift.org/t/unsafemutablepointer-allocation-compatibility-with-c-malloc-free/21713

Comment: You learn something new every day. I was going to delete my comment, but I think we should both leave them in case anybody else comes along with the same idea.

Comment: Thanks all! `strdup`/`free` are precisely what I was looking for. It didn't cross my mind at all to use libc, and all of the search results I found concerned providing a string as an argument to a function, where the bridging and memory management is much simpler.